# How to find integer hyperbola points?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$the hyperbola be canonical.
>   Find all integer points of the plane that belong to the hyperbola.

My idea:
We can multiply by $(ab)^2$, then it can be rewritten as $(bx-ay)(bx+ay) = (ab)^2$, But this argument does not give much, if $a,b$ not integers, but real. Otherwise, it would be possible to compile a system for each factorization.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: One can certainly imagine a hyperbola still in an explicit form or a parametric one, and something will come of it, but I could not do it adequately.

Comment: If $a^2$  and $b^2$ are integers, call them $m,n,$ you have an indefinite quadratic form $n x^2 - m y^2 = mn.$ If there is any integer solution, there are infinitely many, as quadratic forms have an automorphism group. I do not see that you get much if you allow $a,b$ to be still more general. So, the thing to do is see if this version allows any solutions in integers. It might not.

Comment: Is this question your own?

Comment: Yes, this is my question.